# How can I create custom URL routes?

Tags: url-rewriting, templates, rewrite-rules, mod-rewrite, template-redirect

I have a very peculiar requirement, but hopefully I can explain it without being too confusing. I created a page template where I list some properties I get from an external XML file. So far no problems, and let's say the URL is like this:

```
http://www.example.com/properties/
```

Each property has a link that should redirect the user to a "Single Property" page that displays more information about it. I was wondering if there's a way to make the link like this:

```
http://www.example.com/properties/123
```

Where `123` would be the id of the property. So if I have the URL like `properties/some_id` I want to be able to load a view file (like the `single.php` or `page.php` files), but specific to this URL condition.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 86, accepted):

Add this to your theme's functions.php, or [put it in a plugin](http://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin).

```
add_action( 'init', 'wpse26388_rewrites_init' );
function wpse26388_rewrites_init(){
    add_rewrite_rule(
        'properties/([0-9]+)/?$',
        'index.php?pagename=properties&property_id=$matches[1]',
        'top' );
}

add_filter( 'query_vars', 'wpse26388_query_vars' );
function wpse26388_query_vars( $query_vars ){
    $query_vars[] = 'property_id';
    return $query_vars;
}
```

This adds a rewrite rule which directs requests to `/properties/` with any combination of numbers following to pagename `properties`, with the query var `property_id` set. Just be sure to visit your permalinks settings page and save to flush rewrite rules, so this new rule will be included.

In your `page-properties.php` template, `get_query_var('property_id')` will return the property id if it was set, if it's not then show the default properties page.

Comment: This was CLOSE to working for me but I needed to add: 
add_filter('init','flushRules');  
function flushRules(){
    global $wp_rewrite;
    $wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
}

Comment: @tooshel you definitely don't want to flush rules on every request, it is an expensive operation and will slow your site to a crawl. you only need to flush rules once, on plugin activation, or just by visiting the permalinks settings page.

Comment: Yeah, I get that . . . but when you are testing it's nice that it's in there!

Comment: A smarter rewrite url regexp might be ```^properties/([0-9]+)/?```.  Otherwise it would match something like ```example/properties/1```

Comment: @RyanTaylor are you sure about that? it doesn't capture `example/properties/1` when I test it.

Comment: What is location of page-properties.php file? I put it inside plugin directory. Is that right?

Comment: @FeridMovsumov theme files are always loaded from the current active theme directory, unless you [add a filter](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/#filter-hierarchy) to load them from elsewhere.

Comment: Hello @Milo, this is a beautiful piece of code. Do you know how to make this not clash when using $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1; ?  The function is capturing $page (and leaving it blank) and I'm not able to continue paginating.

Comment: @Milo what you mean with `put it in a plugin.` ? where exactly? Everywher into plugin is possible? or in `wp-content/plugins/myPlugin/myPlugin.php` ?

Comment: The `query_vars` filter seems not to be working (WP 5.7), it throws an error: `Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in wp/wp-includes/class-wp.php on line 296`

Answer (score 11):

Another way to do it:

```
add_action('init', function() {
    add_rewrite_rule( '^properties/([0-9]+)/?',
                      'index.php?pagename=properties&property_id=$matches[1]',
                      'top' );
}, 10, 0);

add_action('init', function() {
    add_rewrite_tag( '%property_id%', '([^&]+)' );
}, 10, 0);
```

[Codex Rewrite API/add rewrite rule](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule)

[Codex Rewrite API/add rewrite tag](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_tag)

Comment: The accepted answer works with 4.7 (and 4.8), not sure why you think it doesn't. Your code is essentially doing the same thing, `add_rewrite_tag` adds the query var to the same array as the `query_vars` filter.

Comment: @Milo it probably didn’t work for me, but I don’t have a 4.7 handy anymore so I can’t check. I will edit my answer.

Comment: @Milo Although I personally prefer rewrite tag, but still tested the accepted answer and it works. Just some personal tastes, though.

Comment: @JackJohansson rewrite tags are necessary when you're using it [in a permastruct](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_permastruct). It's just an extra bit of data that WordPress never uses in this case.

Comment: both rules can be added to the same method, ending up in a cleaner and more useful function to come back to and figure out if doing maintenance work