# unexpected problem in url rewrite

Tags: url-rewriting, htaccess

As per the answer provided in [How to create custom URL routes?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/26388/how-to-create-custom-url-routes#answer-26394) I have created the rewrite rule using the same function provided.

```
add_action( 'init', 'wpse26388_rewrites_init' );
function wpse26388_rewrites_init(){
    add_rewrite_rule(
        'gallery/([0-9]+)/?$',
        'gallery?custom_gallery_id=$1',
        'top' );        
}
```

After the flushing of the rules `.htaccess` file was having the following rule :

```
RewriteRule ^gallery/([^/]+)/?$ /wordpress/gallery?custom_gallery_id=$1 [QSA,L]
```

upto this point everything was fine then I tried to make some modifications in the rule like

```
add_action( 'init', 'wpse26388_rewrites_init' );
    function wpse26388_rewrites_init(){
        add_rewrite_rule(
            'topic/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/gallery/([0-9]+)/?$',
            'gallery?custom_gallery_id=$3',
            'top' );        
    }
```

this doesn't seems to be working at all. can anybody help me over this?
thanks in advance.

Comment: the important difference between your rewrite rule and the one you linked is that the one in the other question points to a WordPress *page*, and doesn't result in an *external* rewrite in .htaccess, it's an *internal* rewrite handled entirely within WordPress. please amend your question to clarify exactly what you're trying to load- what are `topic` and `gallery` exactly?

Comment: @Milo gallery is a page to which I am passing a post id of which the attachment images are needed to be fetched as a gallery.
refer this link http://newsmirror.agstechnologies.com/gallery?id=322

Comment: @Milo also refer this link http://newsmirror.agstechnologies.com/topic/place/new-delhi this is the custom post page for which I want to create a galley page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first, you need to add your `custom_gallery_id` to query vars if you haven't already:

```
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'wpse26388_query_vars' );
function wpse26388_query_vars( $query_vars ){
    $query_vars[] = 'custom_gallery_id';
    return $query_vars;
}
```

for your rewrite rule, you need to load a *WordPress object*- a page, a category, etc., and all internal rewrites *must* point to index.php. if topic, place, and new delhi are all pages, it would look something like this:

```
function wpse26388_rewrites_init(){
    add_rewrite_rule(
        'topic/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/gallery/([0-9]+)/?$',
        'index.php?pagename=topic/$matches[1]/$matches[2]&custom_gallery_id=$matches[3]',
        'top' );        
}
```

also try out [this plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/monkeyman-rewrite-analyzer/) for analyzing and testing your rewrite rules.

Comment: can you please elaborate more on `for your rewrite rule, you need to load a WordPress object- a page, a category, etc.` . Sorry I am a newbie so unable to understand in a first stroke.

Comment: I tried adding your code but the query variable is not getting set so I am unable to access the value of `custom_gallery_id` on the gallery page. any suggestions?