# Can WP give a value a post ID?

Tags: permalinks, database, links

So I have queried out some data from another DB and obviously they're not a `post` which means I can't use the standard `permalink` to link them to an existing page with it's `post type`.
So I thought that if WP could just generate an let's say "artificial" post ID to link to a certain generated page like any other `custom post type`.

So basically a generated page like when you do `the_permalink` but for data from another database that is and will not go into the Wordpress DB as a `post` or whatsoever, the question would be if this is possible?

My code so far:

```
$result    = $newdb->get_results("SELECT ".$column1.",".$column2."  FROM ... LIMIT 1 ");
    <?php   
        foreach ($result as $results) { 
            echo '<li id="list">' ;?>
        <a href=" *answer should be here I think* "><?php echo $results->member_name; ?> </a> 
    <?php
            echo '</li>' ;
        } ?>
```

EDIT: I think I got a little further the link now updates into `localhost/wordpress?1` . It refreshes the page but I need it to go to it's unique page(for ex and empty page with only the css)

This is the code now:

```
$result    = $newdb->get_results("SELECT ".$column1.",".$column2."  FROM ... LIMIT 1 ");
        foreach ($result as $results) { 
            echo '<li id="list">' ;?>
            <a href="<?php echo '?id='.$results->memberID.'';  ?>"><?php echo $results->member_name; ?> </a> 
        <?php
            echo '</li>' ;
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Add a rewrite rule](http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule) and [extra query vars](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/query_vars) to handle incoming requests, direct the rewrite rule to a single `page` post type, create a [custom page template](http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates) for that page, then do whatever querying you need using the query vars set by your rewrite rule.

Comment: I'm not sure how that should work with URL's. All I can think of is to rewrite pretty URL's in some sort using the rewrite URL but there's no `post type` involving this, it's I think just like php? Where you'd make an URL in php using the ID(In my case an ID from the other DB) and just redirect towards there but I haven't been successful in doing so..Also I'm clueless as to how i'd use the `Add rewrite rule`.


Note: The information out of the second DB is NOT a `post type` just a plain query.

Comment: your rewrite rule would point to a single WordPress page, setting either the `pagename` or `page_id` query var, then whatever extra data is in your URL would be used to set your own query vars that you use to query data from your own table.

Comment: I've tried something similar with no success, is it maybe possible to give me an example, i'd greatly appreciate it.

Comment: have a look at [this answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/26394/4771) for an example.

Comment: Will do thank you!
EDIT: The `index.php` may that also be `?p=123` for ex. as I'm on localhost and can't do `page name`.

Comment: then it would be `?pagename=something&your_query_var=123`

Answer (score 0):

What you should do is to create a CPT as a container for displaying your data. For each of the CPT "posts" store relevant meta data to is required to be able to get the data from the other DB, and create the per CPT themes files which will access the DB and display the data.

Comment: So what happens is you'll have an empty CPT in Wp-Admin? If so this is exactly what i'll need.

Comment: What the CPT will actually include as content depends on you. you can even hide the cpt from the admin menu by using the right parameters to the `register_post_type` function.

Comment: I'm aware of few of the parameters but what essentially needs to happen is that the CPT may be filled(as array) but not inserted in the DB so I can at least get the same effect as clicking a `permalink` on a CPT.

Comment: You can't have a CPT which is not in the DB. There are other possible solutions to your needs, like creating your own permalink structure and handling everything in your code but IMO the CPT way is the easiest way even if the price you pay is some "garbage" in the DB.

Comment: No the CPT can be in the database, but the information that you'd usually create by doing "New Item" for ex. that can't be in the DB. Wondering if that's possible, because I have the data from the other DB as well as an ID I can appoint that WP just needs to recognize as `CPT post`.

Comment: In a CPT you can create as much information as you desire, even none at all (empty strings for titles and content). If you don't care much about the size of the DB it is really irrelevant for what you actually want to do.

Comment: Hmm I get the idea but I don't see how you could use a CPT as array to save information without inserting it or better said I'd have no idea how to do it. I know how to make a CPT but have no idea how you'd turn that into for example a `while` that has arrays like this `$Number = ["number"]` like I normally would in PHP. Do you perhaps have an example or something I could read? Besides that thank you for the help.

Comment: Guess I don't understand the question. Why would you like to do that on a CPT? You might want to do it on your data but that is something unrelated to the CPT. CPT in your case is just an easy way to create a uniq URL for your data.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13731/discussion-between-david-h-and-mark-kaplun) I'll explain right away!