# Multiple pages per post (not pagination)

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, pages

I'm making a movie database and need to have multiple pages per post: details, cast, recommendations, reviews (something like IMDb). I would prefer to not use any plugins if possible. I'm not new to wordpress but I don't have any clue how to do this. I was looking for help on the internet but every article was about splitting long posts using pagination. So the question is **how to make multiple pages per post?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a custom post type, e.g. `movies` and then you can have some rewrite rule which will basically render something like this `movies/movieId/ratings` to `movies/movieId/?page=ratings`.

So now you can use `$_GET['page']` to check what data you have to show.

How to rewrite the slug in WordPress? Google it.

Check [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/26388/how-to-create-custom-url-routes) answer for rewrite rules.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly, and you want a single post to contain the data for multiple pages of content.  Then maybe use tabs.  If your theme is bootstrap based than this is super easy.

https://mdbootstrap.com/components/tabs/

Comment: I was thinking about it but considering the amount of elements each tab would contain and ux it's not a good option. The most important thing is that i need individual url's for each page, so tabs are definitely out