# Rewrite the default post object's permalink

Tags: url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

In my default WordPress post type, I have a custom field that is named template, which can have a value of either `blog` or `music`.

I want to rewrite the permalink to be something like `%music/my-song` where `my-song` would be the name of the post.

I changed the permalink settings to custom structure `/%template%/%postname%/`.

I've added a `post_link` filter to update the template in the link:

```
add_filter('post_link', function($link, $post = null){

    if($post && ($template = get_field($template, $post->ID)))
        return str_replace('%template%', $template, $link);

    return $link;

});
```

I also added a rewrite tag for WordPress to detect the template:

```
add_rewrite_tag('%template%', '([^/]+', 'template=');
```

Once I save the permalinks, every thing seems to be working for my posts.
However, when I try to access a page, it doesn't work.

For example, my contact page's permalink is `/contact`, and instead of displaying the contact page itself, it shows the home page.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create custom URL routes?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/26388/how-to-create-custom-url-routes)

Comment: It's funny that it even works at all, you forgot to set the number of arguments to the filter (eg: `add_filter('post_link', function, 10, 2)` )