# Landing function through URL

Tags: javascript, site-url

I have a landing page with 3 buttons that have respective functions with them to hide/unhide content based on user selection of those three buttons.

Is there a way I can have the user land directly on a particular function?

so the base URL is domain.com/page

domain.com/page/function1 would land on the page with function1 enabled.

Comment: What type of function? JavaScript/jQuery? PHP?

Comment: Oh sorry about the delay. I didn't see the notification. It's javascript native

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options.

---

**GET Parameter**
The easiest one is to add a `GET` parameter to the url of the links, so you call it like this: `domain.com/page?function=1`

Then, on your `page` page, you can access this parameter using global array `$_GET['function']` and do your logic as you wish.

---

**POST Parameter** - wrap into forms
If you don't want it to be seen, you can wrap your links in separate `form` elements, with `action` set to `domain.com/page`, the link would be an input `type='submit'`, and also add an input field `type='hidden'` with `name='function' value='1'`. Then you can access this value on your `page` page with global `$_POST['function']` array. More about forms [here](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp).

---

**Register custom routes**
You can do exactly like you wanted, accessing `domain.com/page/1` can make the `get_query_var('function')` set to `1` on `page` page, but you need to register a custom url route in WordPress.

This has been answered already, so I'll just point you to it [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/26388/how-to-create-custom-url-routes).

---

**Warning**
Whatever option you choose, please don't forget to wrap the value of your parameter inside `htmlspecialchars()` function. More about that [here](https://code-maven.com/accept-get-and-post-parameters-in-php).

Comment: Sorry for delayed response. Thanks, dboris. Pardon me for being a little new to this. I'll explore these a little bit more and find what works.