# Custom URL routes

Tags: redirect, rewrite-rules, template-redirect

I'm a newbie in Wordpress, so excuse me if I ask a noob question.

I want to redirect some of the URLs to a specific page (single-deal.php). Now, these set of URLs (regex provided for these URLS) does not exist on my server. So, currently my WP returns 404 error. However, I still want to load `single-deal.php` and let it decide.

My `single-deal.php` fires a GET request to an API, and my processing will follow thereafter.

For eg:- If I have an url (for eg) `/properties/1/`  and it's permalink is not available in my WP settings, I want it load `single-deal.php` page, and let my API decide the further processing.

Here's what I've tried reading on multiple other [questions](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/26388/how-to-create-custom-url-routes):-

```
add_action( 'init', 'wpse26388_rewrites_init' );
function wpse26388_rewrites_init(){
    add_rewrite_rule(
        'properties/([0-9]+)/?$',
        'single-deal.php?pagename=single-deal&property_id=$matches[1]',
        'top' );
}

add_filter( 'query_vars', 'wpse26388_query_vars' );
function wpse26388_query_vars( $query_vars ){
    $query_vars[] = 'property_id';
    return $query_vars;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

All internal rewrite rules must point to `index.php`. This isn't a theme file, it's the main bootstrap file in the root of your WordPress install. So, your rule should look like:

```
add_action( 'init', 'wpse26388_rewrites_init' );
function wpse26388_rewrites_init(){
    add_rewrite_rule(
        'properties/([0-9]+)/?$',
        'index.php?pagename=single-deal&property_id=$matches[1]',
        'top'
    );
}
```

You can then assign the `deal.php` template to your `single-deal` page in the admin interface, or you can use the [`page_template`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/page_template) filter if you want to apply conditional template loading, like for example only if your `property_id` query var is set.

Comment: Thanks @Milo for the answer. However, there was a little confusion(typo). My bad. `deal.php` and `single-deal.php` are the same pages. Please check the updated question. Thanks :)

Comment: I think you're confusing pages and templates. Your rewrite rule should point to `index.php`, and the `pagename` query var should point to a `page` slug. That page is then associated with a template.

Comment: How and where can I find page slug (associated to template `single-deal.php`)?

Comment: I tried `echo get_page_template_slug($post->ID);` in my template file (ie `single-deal.php`), but it shows nothing.

Comment: Templates don't have page slugs. You log in to admin interface, go to `Pages`, create a page, give it a slug. There is a meta box on the page edit screen that lets you select template, you choose your custom template. Now you use the slug of this newly created page in your rewrite rule. When the page loads, WordPress loads your template.

Comment: Okay. So, I passed a page slug and it worked wonders.
However, the theme that I've downloaded does not have any template associated with `single-deal.php`. Any thoughts?

Comment: As a side note, whenever I create a new deal on WP dshboard, `single-deal.php` renders its information.

Comment: Here is it's documentation:- http://edeals.re/th%C3%A8me%20%C3%A0%20charger/documentation/#creating-a-deal

Comment: Okay. I just understood what `add_rewrite_rule` does. It routes the matched url to the page with query parameters (if required).

HOWEVER, my requirement is not to route. I want to load the `single-deal.php` when a regex matched URL is browsed. This URL does not exist on my server.

Please provide help!

Comment: Any thoughts on this please?

Comment: So deals is a custom post type? How is that related to your api call? I don’t know what else to tell you. You can’t just load a template file with no main query object. Rewrites generate a main query and the template is chosen based on the results of the main query.