# Use URI suffix as parameter and ignore when resolving page

Tags: url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

I'm trying to change the output of `page`s depending on the URIs last section. This will be used to enable the user to change the page's presentation by changing the URL (e.g. `/path/to/page/xml` would show the `page`'s content as XML).

The mode-selector should be ignored when Wordpress queries the page, so all three URIs should result in the same `page` content but add a query-parameter `mode` without doing a redirect (the parameter should be internal only, not visible to the user).

Example:

```
Unchanged Page: /path/to/page

Mode 1:         /path/to/page/mode1 => /path/to/page?mode=m1
Mode 2:         /path/to/page/mode2 => /path/to/page?mode=m2
```

When I add a rule to `.htaccess`, the parameter is added, but the page is not found (404). Wordpress seems to use the original URI, instead of the rewritten one.

I tried varients of the following rule, without success:

```
RewriteRule (.+)/mode1$ $1?mode=m1 [QSA]
```

What am I missing?

Comment: If you don't want the querystrings to be visible to the user, why don't you just use a PHP session instead? Or is there a reason I'm missing? With sessions you can also change the output of a page based on the value you're setting.

Comment: @DeltaG I want the user to be able to change the presentation of the page by changing the URL. Like `.../page/booking` for a booking-process or `.../page/xml` for an XML represendation of the page.

Comment: You should be able to do this using rewrite rules; check out the answer of this question: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/398461/pulling-a-parameter-out-of-the-url-of-a-wp-link-without-or-being-sent-to-a-d/398867#398867

Comment: @Aboelabbas Yes! This helped. I don't know what I did different than all the other times, but it works now. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Aboelabbas gave me the hint I needed. Although I don't really know what I did different, here is the working code for all three modes I need:

```php
<?php
add_filter('query_vars', function ($query_vars) {
  $query_vars[] = 'mode';
  return $query_vars;
});

add_action('init', function () {
  add_rewrite_rule(
    '(.+)/buchung$', // Rule for URLs ending with "/buchung"
    'index.php?pagename=$matches[1]&mode=booking',
    'top'
  );

  add_rewrite_rule(
    '(.+/[^/]+)\.xml$', // Rule for URLs ending with "/anything.xml"
    'index.php?pagename=$matches[1]&mode=xml',
    'top'
  );

  add_rewrite_rule(
    '(.+/[^/]+)\.json$', // Rule for URLs ending with "/anything.json"
    'index.php?pagename=$matches[1]&mode=json',
    'top'
  );
});
```